# Downloading assets in media queries

Tags: html, css

I'm using media queries on my page, if the screen is small, I show some different html code, by toggling the css display property.

For small screens I show:

```
<div id="slot-machine-mobile" class="row show-for-small-only">
    <div class="small-12 small-centered columns">
        <img src="/assets/img/test-img.jpg">
    </div>
</div>
```

But as I understand it, this test mg will be downloaded even if just using a large screen. Is there a way so that the image never downloads if they are using a large screen?

Comment: You could do it with a `background-image`.

Comment: How would this work, would it only download if that particular media query was satisfied?

Comment: @panthro try my code below with jquery ,i used it in a lot of web sites

Answer (score 2):

You can make a block element and assign to it a background-image through css.

```
<div class="img">

img { background-image:url("test-img.jpg"); }
```

So your HTML coud look something like this:

```
<div id="slot-machine-mobile" class="row show-for-small-only">
    <div class="small-12 small-centered columns">
        <div class="img"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: well you should apply a display: block to the div.img some width and height, I didn't specified this because it was out of the question's scope

Answer (score 0):

you can use jquery in this case for the responsive  :
use when you resize the window this code

```
$( window ).resize(function() {
  if($( document ).width()>width_large_screen)
   {
     $('#slot-machine-mobile img').attr('src','....');
    }else
   {
    $('#slot-machine-mobile img').attr('src','....');
   }
});
```

and when the document is ready :

```
$(document).ready(function() {

      if($( document ).width()>width_large_screen)
    {
      $('#slot-machine-mobile img').attr('src','....');
    }else
    {
     $('#slot-machine-mobile img').attr('src','....');
    }
 });
```

try and tell me if it is ok ,good luck